# TYPO3 validation of relation property in model

Tags: validation, extbase, typo3-9.x

I have model in my extbase extension - like below.
By default TYPO3 will validate all author's properties and it's relations recursivelly. Is there possibility in TYPO3 just to validate if author relation exists and not validate all it's (author's) properties and relations recursivelly?

```
class MyModel
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @validate NotEmpty
     */
    protected $title = '';

    /**
     * @var \MyAnotherModel
     * @copy reference
     */
    protected $author;
```

Answer (score 2):

Extbase supports two types of validation (see https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/9-CrosscuttingConcerns/2-validating-domain-objects.html)

- model validation
- controller-action validation

When using (complete) model validation on aggregate roots that means that all involved aggregates need to pass validation as well - in other words, there is no conditional validation that can be enabled/disabled individually.

From what I understood from your scenario and your goal is:

- ignore property validation on `Author` (`MyAnotherModel` in initial source)
- just assert cardinality of `author` property (`MyModel.author` in initial source)

This could be done via controller-action validation, like shown below.

#### New custom validator

```
class MyModelCardinalityValidator extends AbstractValidator
{
    public function isValid($value)
    {
        if (!$value instanceof MyModel) {
            throw new \LogicException('...');
        }
        if ($value->getAuthor() === null) {
            $this->addError('Author is missing', 1577381508);
            // 1577381508 = unix-timestamp as "unique error code"
        }
    }
}
```

#### `@Validate` in controller-action

```
class MyController extends ActionController
{
    /**
     * @param MyModel $model
     * @TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Annotation\Validate("NamespaceTo\MyModelCardinalityValidator", param="model")
     */
    public function myAction(MyModel $model)
    {
        // your application code
    }
}
```

#### References

- documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/9-CrosscuttingConcerns/2-validating-domain-objects.html
- example source code in context: https://github.com/HofUniversityIndieOne2019/book-store-project/tree/cd14c2f58a7f15180a5113e9dbfa97c9fda66644/packages/book_store_app

  - custom validator: https://github.com/HofUniversityIndieOne2019/book-store-project/blob/cd14c2f58a7f15180a5113e9dbfa97c9fda66644/packages/book_store_app/Classes/Validator/BankAccountValidator.php
  - `@Validate` annotation in controller: https://github.com/HofUniversityIndieOne2019/book-store-project/blob/cd14c2f58a7f15180a5113e9dbfa97c9fda66644/packages/book_store_app/Classes/Controller/CustomerController.php#L130